# Tricky Trigonometric Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How do we solve  $\int x^3\sqrt{4+x^2}dx$? I think I substituted the wrong thing in and got the wrong answer. I've tried multiple times and cant figure it out. I got that the  $\sqrt{4+x^2}= 2\sec(\theta)$. Don't know what to do from there.

Comment: This question is tagged definite-integrals but you have not mentioned any limits of integration.  Also, "I got that the square root = 2sec(theta)" doesn't make any sense.  The square root of what?  Please fix this, otherwise we can't help you and this question will be at risk of being closed.

Comment: I worked out what was in the square root first and got that it equals 2sec(theta)

Comment: @Chris, what you really mean is that you tried a substitution, right? There is more than one possible substitution, another choice is shown in DonAntonio's answer below. A better choice, in my opinion

Comment: I realize that now that I could have used integration by parts instead

Comment: The irony of the title - the integral is neither tricky nor trigonometric. Although both points can be argued ;)

Comment: Yes you can use trig substitution here bud. And I found it tricky.

Comment: @Chris That **still** doesn't make it a trigonometric integral...

Comment: Okay my bad...I hope no one got offended by this integral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: with

$$\begin{cases}u=x^2,&u'=2x\\{}\\v'=x\sqrt{4+x^2},&v=\frac13(4+x^2)^{3/2}\end{cases}\implies\int x^3\sqrt{4+x^2}\,dx=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac13x^2(4+x^2)^{3/2}-\frac23\int x(4+x^2)^{3/2}\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$u=4+x^2\to\text{d}u=2x\text{d}x\implies \int x^3\sqrt{u}\frac{\text{d}u}{2x}$ $=\frac{1}{2}\int(4-u)u^{1/2}\text{d}u$ can you move forward from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use the substitution
$$
4+x^2=t
$$
that gives 
$$
x^3dx=\frac{1}{2}(t-4)dt
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x=2\tan \theta$, we have
\begin{align*}
I=\int x^3\sqrt{4+x^2}dx&=16\int \tan^3\theta \sec \theta(1+\tan^2\theta) d\theta=16\int\frac{\sin^3\theta}{\cos^6\theta}d\theta\\&=16\int\frac{\sin\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)}{\cos^6\theta}d\theta
\end{align*}
 set $\cos\theta=u$, therefore
$$I=-16\int\frac{1-u^2}{u^6}du=\frac{16}{5u^5}-\frac{16}{3u^3}+c$$